# Property file key value - getting value of one key based on another key's value

Tags: java, properties

Input from args will be **A100**. I need to check this value **A100** in property file and obtain the query `select * from xyz` which is the value of another key. How can I check the value in one key and based on it how can i get the value of another key ? Multiple values of view1 (A1000,A200,A300 etc till 50 views) will have only one query `select * from xyz`.

Property file:

```
view1 = A1000,A200,A300 

query1 = select * from xyz

view2 = B100,B200,B300

query2 = select * from abc
```

Code:

```
for(Object k:keys){
    String key = (String)k;     
    String [] mapValue = Properties.getProperty(key).split(",");
    List<String> lList=Arrays.asList(mapValue);
    if(key.startsWith("view") &&(lList.contains(tmpSrc.getSourceTableForUpdate()))){        
        dest.seteQuery(Properties.getProperty("")); // here i need to get the query1 value.
    }
}
```

Please advise on this.

Comment: how view1 and query1 are related? that's just a convention you use? You can preprocess your data from properties file for fast queries. Or perhaps you can store your data differently, e.g. xml/json.

Comment: Is there a reason for this file to have that structure as opposed to some XML or JSON configuration? Besides that you could try to replace `view` with `query` and use that as the key, e.g. `String queryKey = key.replaceAll("view","query");`.

Comment: @Borys Zibrov  thanks for the reply.  I cannot use Json or XML as this requirement is to remove Json and externalize the query which is common to various views. So all the view which has same query is kept in view1 key. If i get any of the value from View1, i have to execute the query found in query1.

Comment: Thomas - sorry i dint get u. Can u pls explain in details? how replacing will help here?

Comment: What do you have as input? I bet your input is `A1000` or `B2341`. Then this code `String [] mapValue = Properties.getProperty(key).split(",");` is not correct, as `A1000` is not a key but a value

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have as input? I bet your input is `A1000` or `B2341`. Then this code `String [] mapValue = Properties.getProperty(key).split(",");` is not correct, as `A1000` is not a key but a value. If that's the case your best bet is to preprocess all the properties from your property file:

```
Map<String, String> queriesByKeys = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : props.keySet())
{
    if (!key.startsWith("view"))
        continue;

    String queryKey = key.replace("view", "query");
    String queryValue = props.getPropertyValue(queryKey);

    String ids = props.getPropertyValue(key);
    for (String id : ids.split(","))
        queriesByKeys.put(id, queryValue);
}
```

Then you can use `queriesByKeys` to get query by ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot Borys! Its working as I expected. Thanks for Thomas as well for your response!